# Grid view missing Horizondal scroll bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, scrollbars

DataGridView is not showing the horizontal scroll bar. I tried all the following

1. set the Scroll bar:both
2. Frozen property of all cells to false
3. AutoSizeColumnMode:AllCells

Comment: But are actually columns/data missing??? The HScrollBar will __only show when needed__, even if the ScrollBars is Both.

Comment: grid view contains data

Comment: So? Are data __missing__???? If all columns are fully visible the Scrollbar will not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `AutoSizeColumnMode` to `None`

**Edited as per OP's request**

If problem persist then,

Delete that `DataGridView` and drag-drop new `DataGridView` and give the same name of the old `DataGridView` and check.

Comment: @SruthiSuresh I have not even change any of the properties in datagridview. It works for me.

Comment: @SruthiSuresh delete that datagridview and drag-drop new datagridview and give the same name of the old datagridview and check.

Comment: i replaced my datagrid as you said.now  the scroll bars are visible.thank you

Comment: @SruthiSuresh great.. glad it helped. please mark answer as accepted by clicking the green tick aside it. and if you found it useful you may also want to up-vote it. thank you

Comment: plese add your comment that helped me as the answer

Comment: @SruthiSuresh I have added the comment section into answer as well.